# How to switch output audio from analog to bluetooth and vice versa

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

i'm working on a raspberry pi 3 with bluetooth built in with

```
    kernel : 4.4.38-v7+
    pulseaudio : 5.0
    bluez : 5.23-2+rpi2
```

I'm trying to switch from analog output to bluetooth output with a pir sensor to make the sound follow me in my studio.

From now here's my code in Nodejs

I'm just muting the sound on kodi but it was a test to communicate with kodi for later.

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio,pir = new Gpio(4, 'in', 'both');
var kodi = require('kodi-ws');


kodi('localhost',9090).then(function(connection){

pir.watch(function(err, value) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('erreur de lecture du capteur')
    exit();
  }

  if(!value){
    connection.Application.SetMute(true);

  }else{
    connection.Application.SetMute(false);
  }
});

console.log('Pi watcher deployed successfully!');
console.log('Keep dancing');

});
function exit() {
  pir.unexport();
  process.exit();
}
```

Instead of muting , i would try to use shelljs to send the command to switch audio but already tried with pulseaudio and `pacmd` with no success for now.

thank you in advance for answers